# Access denied embedding swf object in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url, flash

I am trying to currently embed a media player into certain web content and seem to be having strange problems in IE (all versions tested so far 6->8).

[Here is a page](http://www.equalitysouthwest.org.uk/our-networks/disability/signed-pages.html) with the player embedded in it. You can view it in FF or a webkit browser and it should work fine. In IE the flash part of it fails to load without error. (It errors when you try and use the buttons, but that's because the flash embedding has already failed).

The javascript for the player code can be found [here](http://www.equalitysouthwest.org.uk/esw/live/javascript/jquery.player.js) (function generateFlashPlayer(): line 216+ is the part trying to load the swf object).

The strangest part is that the swf itself is located [here](http://www.equalitysouthwest.org.uk/esw/live/javascript/player.swf) and while I can access it fine using FF or webkits I simply can't access it using IE - it just results in  a little red cross in the top left.

I found [this blog](http://blog.guya.net/2008/09/10/bug-in-internet-explorer-security-model-when-embedding-flash/) which seemed to hint that reloading the page should help, but reloading the swf in the above link doesn't change the outcome at all.

I should note that I can't duplicate this locally. Locally the player works fine in all IEs I've tested it in.

Has anyone got any ideas/suggestions/thoughts? I'm kind of tearing my hair out at this point :(

EDIT:
My flash in IE was corrupted, which played a fairly large part in failing to debug the issue successfully.
The secondary issue however appeared to be that creating an element in jQuery and embedding flash into it immediately seems to have potential issues in IE. I fixed the secondary problem by wrapping the embed code for the flash in a `setTimeout(function() {}, 0);` and it seemed to work.

(more detailed writeup [here](http://www.hallofbrightcarvings.com/ie-dom-updating/) just in case someone else runs across what I currently thinking is the most obscure bug I've ever dealt with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is in embeding (html/css/js) try other methods such as swfobject or the one flash generates itself. If it works, then you have to concentrate on embedding faults.

Another weird problem I had embedding in ie, comes with the http headers. If you need to load external data from a flash movie in IE, and the page has http headers with no-cache paradigm on, the simply flash will fail to load external data. This is IE voodoo.

Also, if you prevent caching, flash movie will not be able to load ven a crossdomain file. Things get even worse on ssl.

I hope it helped...

Try this, could give you more info: http://faindu.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/ie7-ssl-xml-flex-error-2032-stream-error/